# Adding string after a specific string using sed Unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a string in a file like this:

```
"Value1=[random number]"
```

After this string I want to add another string, specifically:

```
"Value2=100"
```

If I try to use:

```
sed  '/Value1=/a Value2=100' myfile.txt
```

It will fail because I have not included the fact that Value1=[some random number].

How do I add the condition that Value1=random number and Value2 should be added to this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed  '/Value1=[0-9]\+/a Value2=100' myfile.txt
```

The `[0-9]\+` will match any string of digits.  For example, on my cygwin, GNU sed 4.2.2,

```
echo Value1=42 | sed '/Value1=[0-9]\+/a Value2=43'
```

produces

```
Value1=42
Value2=43
```

**Edit**: If the number may or may not be in double-quotes, use:

```
 sed '/Value1="\?[0-9]\+"\?/a Value2=43'
```

The `"\?` is an optional double-quote.

Comment: What if the number is surrounded by quotes?  Does this mean it's no longer a number, but a string?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$ sed 's,\(Value1=200\),\1 Value2=100,' myfile.txt
```

Result:

```
Value1=200 Value2=100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '"Value1=400"' | sed 's/"Value1=.*"/&\n"Value2=100"/'
```

Output:

```
"Value1=400"
"Value2=100"
```

Or:

```
echo '"Value1=400"' | sed 's/"Value1=.*"/& "Value2=100"/'
```

Output:

```
"Value1=400" "Value2=100"
```